# How to add new columns into a new dataframe using output of single function call having multiple arguments and multiple return fields?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

this is continuation to below post:

[How to add/insert output of a function call that returns multiple fields, as new columns into Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110840/how-to-add-insert-output-of-a-function-call-that-returns-multiple-fields-as-new/65111007?)

If a function returns multiple fields from two different arguments, how to use apply() or add them altogether in a new pandas dataframe ?

Sample code:

```
    from pandas import DataFrame
    People_List = [['Jon','Smith',21],['Mark','Brown',38],['Maria','Lee',42],['Jill','Jones',28],['Jack','Ford',55]]
    df1 = DataFrame (People_List,columns=['First_Name','Last_Name','Age'])
    Address_List = [['Jon','Chicago'],['Mark','SFO'],['Maria','Chicago'],['Jill','Chicago'],['Jack','Chicago']]
    df2 = DataFrame(Address_List,columns=['First_Name', 'City'])
    print (df1, df2)
```

```
      First_Name Last_Name  Age
    0        Jon     Smith   21
    1       Mark     Brown   38
    2      Maria       Lee   42
    3       Jill     Jones   28
    4       Jack      Ford   55  
 
      First_Name     City
    0        Jon  Chicago
    1       Mark      SFO
    2      Maria  Chicago
    3       Jill  Chicago
    4       Jack  Chicago
```

```
def getTitleBirthYear(df1, df2):
    if 'Maria' in df1.First_Name:
        title='Ms'
    else:
        title='Mr' 
    current_year = int('2020')
    birth_year=''
    age = df1.Age
    birth_year = current_year - age
    if 'Chicago' in df2.City:
        state='IL'
    else:
        state='Other'
    return title,birth_year,state
    #return {'title':title,'birth_year':birth_year, 'state':state}

getTitleBirthYear(df1,df2)

  title birth_year state
0 Mr    1999       IL
1 Mr    1982       Other
2 Ms    1978       IL
3 Mr    1992       IL
4 Mr    1965       IL

df = DataFrame.merge(df1,df2,on='First_Name',how='inner')
print(df)
```

```
      First_Name Last_Name  Age     City
    0        Jon     Smith   21  Chicago
    1       Mark     Brown   38      SFO
    2      Maria       Lee   42  Chicago
    3       Jill     Jones   28  Chicago
    4       Jack      Ford   55  Chicago
```

```
df['title', 'birth_year', 'state'] = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(getTitleBirthYear,axis=1).tolist())
```

However, getting below error:
**TypeError: ("getTitleBirthYear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df2'", 'occurred at index 0')**

final expected output:

```
  First_Name Last_Name  Age City    title   birth_year  state
0        Jon     Smith   21 Chicago     Mr      1999        IL
1       Mark     Brown   38 SFO     Mr      1982        Other
2      Maria       Lee   42 Chicago     Ms      1978        IL  
3       Jill     Jones   28 Chicago     Mr      1992        IL
4       Jack      Ford   55 Chicago     Mr      1965        IL
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from right side instead your function:

```
import numpy as np

df = df1.merge(df2,on='First_Name')
df['title'] = np.where(df['First_Name'].eq('Maria'), 'Ms', 'Mr')
df['birth_year'] = df['Age'].rsub(2020)
df['state'] = np.where(df['City'].eq('Chicago'), 'IL', 'Other')
print (df)
  First_Name Last_Name  Age     City title  birth_year  state
0        Jon     Smith   21  Chicago    Mr        1999     IL
1       Mark     Brown   38      SFO    Mr        1982  Other
2      Maria       Lee   42  Chicago    Ms        1978     IL
3       Jill     Jones   28  Chicago    Mr        1992     IL
4       Jack      Ford   55  Chicago    Mr        1965     IL
```

Your method should be changed with `result_type='expand'` in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), assigned columns to list `['title', 'birth_year', 'state']` (added `[]`), changed function for check by `==` instead `in`.

But solution is slowier/ complicated, so better is use first one.

```
def getTitleBirthYear(x):
    if x.First_Name == 'Maria' :
        title='Ms'
    else:
        title='Mr' 
    current_year = int('2020')
    birth_year=''
    age = x.Age
    birth_year = current_year - age
    if x.City == 'Chicago':
        state='IL'
    else:
        state='Other'
    return title,birth_year,state

    
df = df1.merge(df2,on='First_Name')
    
df[['title', 'birth_year', 'state']] = df.apply(getTitleBirthYear,
                                                axis=1, 
                                                result_type='expand')
print (df)
  First_Name Last_Name  Age     City title  birth_year  state
0        Jon     Smith   21  Chicago    Mr        1999     IL
1       Mark     Brown   38      SFO    Mr        1982  Other
2      Maria       Lee   42  Chicago    Ms        1978     IL
3       Jill     Jones   28  Chicago    Mr        1992     IL
4       Jack      Ford   55  Chicago    Mr        1965     IL
```

Answer (score 0):

You function doesn't need two input args if you can merge the df before hand

`df = df1.merge(df2,on='First_Name')`

```
def getTitleBirthYear(x):
    if x.First_Name == 'Maria' :
        title='Ms'
    else:
        title='Mr' 
    current_year = int('2020')
    birth_year=''
    age = x.Age
    birth_year = current_year - age
    if x.City == 'Chicago':
        state='IL'
    else:
        state='Other'
    return title,birth_year,state
```

However as stated by @jezrael, this approach is much slower, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938318/why-apply-sometimes-isnt-faster-than-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe)

`df[['title', 'birth_year', 'state']] = df.apply(getTitleBirthYear, axis=1, result_type='expand'`

```
  First_Name Last_Name  Age     City title  birth_year  state
0        Jon     Smith   21  Chicago    Mr        1999     IL
1       Mark     Brown   38      SFO    Mr        1982  Other
2      Maria       Lee   42  Chicago    Ms        1978     IL
3       Jill     Jones   28  Chicago    Mr        1992     IL
4       Jack      Ford   55  Chicago    Mr        1965     IL
```